# PHP gallery integrating CSS

Tags: php, css, integration

i have this code made in PHP , i integrated a css code by `<<<HTML` using variable $style the style shows up 3 times in the back of images for the gallerys, i suspect 3 times it shows up because of the number of the images, my wish was to show up only once.

i don't get it what it shows up by the number of images ? !

```
<?php
if( ! defined( 'CMSFUTURE' ) ) {
    die( "Hacking attempt!" );
}
$style = <<<HTML
<style>
.gallerypro{padding:5px 5px 0 5px;height: 120px; width: 543px; background-color: rgb(220,220,220); border:1px solid grey; box-shadow: 7px 8px 20px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.47);}
</style>
HTML;
$distr_charset = "utf-8";
$self_id ='';
$homeUrl = $config['http_home_url'];
$rootPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$fullpath = $rootPath."/uploads/jmgallery/";
include ('engine/api/api.class.php');
if($dle_module == "showfull") {
$id = $_GET['newsid'];
$getCg = $dle_api->load_table($table="dle_jmgallery", $fields="id", $where="id > 0", $multirow="false", $start="0", $limit="0", $sort="", $sort_order="");
$having = FALSE;
  foreach($getCg as $g){
    if($g['id'] == $id){$having = TRUE;}
  }
if($having == TRUE){
$getGal = $dle_api->load_table($table="dle_jmgallery", $fields="*", $where="id > 0", $multirow="true", $start="0", $limit="0", $sort="", $sort_order="");
  foreach($getGal as $carousel){
      $sizeW = $carousel['sizew'];
      $sizeH = $carousel['sizeh'];
      $dist = $carousel['distance']; 
      $self_id = $carousel['id'];    
      if($self_id == $id){
        $mask = "*.jpg";
        $idN = $fullpath.$id."/";
        $mask = $idN.$mask;
        if($sizeH == "0"){$sizeH = $sizeW; }
        foreach (glob($mask) as $filename) {
          $fileRname = substr($filename, -14);
          $picSizeW = $sizeW * 2;
          $img = "<img src='/uploads/jmgallery/$id/$fileRname' width='".$picSizeW."px' />";
          $galery .= "$style<div class='gallerypro'><a style='overflow:hidden; display:block; float:left; margin:".$dist."px 0 0 ".$dist."px; width:".$sizeW."px; height:".$sizeH."px;'  href='".$homeUrl."uploads/jmgallery/$id/$fileRname' onclick='return hs.expand(this)'>$img</a>"; } $xJ ="Computer repair"; $xJ = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8", $xJ); $galery .="<a href='$sitename' style='display:none; '>$xJ</a></div>";
          echo $galery."<br clear='left' />";
      }
    }
  }
  $having = FALSE;
}
?>
```

This is the result i get :
[image]

See in the background of images ? that style is from variable $style declared above , and used in :

```
$galery .= "$style<div class='gallerypro'><a style='overflow:hidden; display:block; float:left; margin:".$dist."px 0 0 ".$dist."px; width:".$sizeW."px; height:".$sizeH."px;'  href='".$homeUrl."uploads/jmgallery/$id/$fileRname' onclick='return hs.expand(this)'>$img</a>"; } $xJ ="Computer repair"; $xJ = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8", $xJ); $galery .="<a href='$sitename' style='display:none; '>$xJ</a></div>";
```

Comment: move (echo $galery."<br clear='left' />";) outside the (foreach) loop as its echoing the gallery each time it finds an image

Comment: Thanks for answering,  Removing , moving , that line causes the gallery to not show up at all...

Answer (score 0):

Move `$style` out of foreach statement.

If you place it inside foreach, it will displayed as many as foreach loop.

I don't know why you used to many foreach.
Just another suggestion, make up your code for better debugging. You also need to know about how to place a container/wrapper for your element.
See update of your code.

```
<?php
if( ! defined( 'CMSFUTURE' ) ) {
    die( "Hacking attempt!" );
}
$style = <<<HTML
<style>
.gallerypro{padding:5px 5px 0 5px;height: 120px; width: 543px; background-color: rgb(220,220,220); border:1px solid grey; box-shadow: 7px 8px 20px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.47);}
</style>
HTML;
$distr_charset = "utf-8";
$self_id    ='';
$homeUrl    = $config['http_home_url'];
$rootPath   = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$fullpath   = $rootPath."/uploads/jmgallery/";
include ('engine/api/api.class.php');
if($dle_module == "showfull") {
    $id = $_GET['newsid'];
    $getCg = $dle_api->load_table($table="dle_jmgallery", $fields="id", $where="id > 0", $multirow="false", $start="0", $limit="0", $sort="", $sort_order="");
    $having = FALSE;
    foreach($getCg as $g){
        if($g['id'] == $id){$having = TRUE;}
    }
    if($having == TRUE){
        $getGal = $dle_api->load_table($table="dle_jmgallery", $fields="*", $where="id > 0", $multirow="true", $start="0", $limit="0", $sort="", $sort_order="");
        $galerry    = $style."<div class='gallerypro'>";
        foreach($getGal as $carousel){
            $sizeW = $carousel['sizew'];
            $sizeH = $carousel['sizeh'];
            $dist = $carousel['distance']; 
            $self_id = $carousel['id'];    
            if($self_id == $id){
                $mask = "*.jpg";
                $idN = $fullpath.$id."/";
                $mask = $idN.$mask;
                if($sizeH == "0"){$sizeH = $sizeW; }
                foreach (glob($mask) as $filename) {
                    $fileRname  = substr($filename, -14);
                    $picSizeW   = $sizeW * 2;
                    $img        = "<img src='/uploads/jmgallery/$id/$fileRname' width='".$picSizeW."px' />";
                    $galery     .= "<a style='overflow:hidden; display:block; float:left; margin:".$dist."px 0 0 ".$dist."px; width:".$sizeW."px; height:".$sizeH."px;'  href='".$homeUrl."uploads/jmgallery/$id/$fileRname' onclick='return hs.expand(this)'>$img</a>";
                }
                $xJ         ="Computer repair";
                $xJ         = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8", $xJ);
                $galery     .="<a href='$sitename' style='display:none; '>$xJ</a>";
            }
        }
        $gallery    .= "</div>";
        echo $gallery;
    }
    $having = FALSE;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hy Redy i try this way to is making my gallery not show up at all, the only thing that shows up after changeing the code this whay is the '<br clear='left' />'

Comment: Yes, that may caused. `br` give 1 empty line, and `clear: left` remove all `float: left` effect to other element.

Comment: That did not work but you give me a idea , this is the whay it worked :  'echo $galery."$gogo <br/>"; added down the $gallery Where $gogo is $gogo = $style. "<div class='gallerypro'>";